# Android: Get Textview value of Spinner on Button click

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` and i am populating it with custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Spinner item layout contains two `TextView`s, One TextView for item id and it is not visible other is for item name. I want to get this item id on button click event then insert it to Sqlite database. I get the id on `setOnItemSelectedListener` of `Spinner` as

```
companySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Get selected row data to show on screen
                String companyId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerItemIdTv)).getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), companyId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, "companyId:" + companyId);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }
        });
```

and Spinner Item Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerItemIdTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerItemNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But couldnt make it on button click. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you not using Tag in textview instead of using separate textview for ID?

Comment: On which button click are you talking about ? Will you make it clear.

Comment: @Revolution what do you mean by Tag ? i am an Android noob

Comment: @ShreeKrishna imagine i have a form in an Activity. There is a Spinner as i mentioned above, EditTexts etc and a button. Make sense ?

Comment: Can you please post your xml code?

Comment: @Revolution which xml you want me to post ? For spinner or spinner item layout ?

Comment: you mean You want to get Spinner's selected Item ID on Button click is it ?

Comment: where your this textview is located. spinnerItemIdTv

Comment: @Revolution there is a xml file for spinenr item which i use in custom spinner adapter. TextViews are located in this file.

Comment: Yes Post this xml Spinner item layout

Comment: @Revolution done, check please

Comment: Did't you get me ? I mean do you want a value of spinner on buttonclick which you got in `onItemSelected`. OR something else. Is value of companyId showing correct result as you expected ?

Comment: Didnt you read the question ? @ShreeKrishna. I think it is clearly expressed. I want to get the value of `spinnerItemIdTv` which is placed in the spinner item layout.

Comment: Ohh ok I got you, I just tried to remind don't be angry, I apologize. I've added an answer, That may help you to get it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for this

```
View selectedView = null;  //Declare it as a class level variable so that you don't need to make it final  

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedView = view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And Inside some Button's click event, do like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                if(selectedView!=null){                        
                    String companyId = ((TextView) selectedView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerItemIdTv)).getText().toString();
                }
               else{//Something}    

            }
        });
```

Comment: That works, thanks. But do you think there is a better solution for implementing a key-value spinner like HTML dropdown ?

Comment: @Tartar Bro I am sorry that I'm not so familiar with custom dropdown or HTML dropdown. And another thing to notice in addition is you can set `selectedView` to null again in `onNothingSelected`.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your answer it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have adapter associated with your Spinner and I suppose you have some data structure associated with Adapter. You can get data you need onItemSelected (something like below)

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    myData = myArrayList.get(i);
//OR
    myData = myAdapter.getItem(i);
}
```

myData can be Activity field and you can use later onClick callback assosiated with your button.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
companySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Spinner spinComp = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_company);
            int selCompIndex = spinComp .getSelectedItemPosition();
            String compID = companyList.get(selCompIndex).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), compID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        }
    });
```

Where, `companyList` is ArrayList which you are passing to Spinner Adapter. Hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `xml` to single `TextView` and use `tag` for ID.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerItemNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="yourId"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now use `setText` to set the spinner row value and use `setTag` to set the ID of row and then get the ID like this.

```
companySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                String companyId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerItemNameTv)).getTag().toString(); //use parent instead.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), companyId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, "companyId:" + companyId);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: Bro i think u did not read my question. I am already doing this by either using the tag or not. That is not the point. Point is getting the value on Button click event.

Comment: No i can not since i am already able to do what you have posted. Thanks though.

Comment: The solution given by @Shree Krishna & using tag with single textView will be more flexible way.